# Print the name of a fact in a document antiquotation

Tags: isabelle

Can I somehow refer to the name of a lemma (or theorem or corollary) inside Isabelle text?

For example:

```
theory Scratch
  imports Main
begin

lemma lemma_name: "stuff = stuff" by simp

text‹As we have proven in fact @{thm lemma_name}, stuff is stuff.›

end
```

When compiling this to pdf, I see

```
As we have proven in fact stuff=stuff, stuff is stuff.
```

I would like to see

```
As we have proven in fact lemma_name, stuff is stuff.
```

Is there some document antiqotation which just prints the name of a lemma?

I could just type the lemma name verbatim, but this neither gives me control-click in the IDE nor does it make sure the text still refers to a true fact, even if I rename lemmas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output of antiquotations can be changed by options explained in [4.2.1 and 4.2.2 of the Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/doc/isar-ref.pdf#page=93). One (rather hidden) option `[source=true]` sets the output to print what you have entered as argument to the antiquotation instead of its output.

```
text ‹As we have proven in fact @{thm [source] lemma_name}, stuff is stuff.
```

...will thus result in the document output:

> As we have proven in fact `lemma_name`, stuff is stuff.

The checking of the validity of the reference will still take place during document preparation.